# PrimeNG, p-tabView placing extra content on tab line

Tags: angular, primeng

I am trying to conserve space on a page that is full, and have a Calendar control that I would like to be accessible from multiple tabs, so I am trying to place the Calendar control on the same row as the tabs for the p-tabView control.  I have stumble along and have not come up with a solution yet.  I have mocked up the situation below:

```
<p-tabView>
  <p-tabPanel header='Daily Expenses'>
    Daily Expenses Content
  </p-tabPanel>
  <p-tabPanel header='Weeky Totals'>
    Weeky Totals Content
  </p-tabPanel>
  <p-tabPanel header='Profile'>
    Employee Profile Content
  </p-tabPanel>
  <li class="ui-corner-top ui-tabview-nav">
    <span class="ui-tabview-title">Calendar control</span>
  </li>
</p-tabView>
```

Suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: you can try this `<p-tabPanel><ng-template pTemplate="header"><span class="ui-tabview-title">Calendar control</span></ng-template></p-tabPanel>` but honestly doesn't that look a bit odd?

Comment: I actually moved the calendar control to another component.  I did not get the above to work.